# Connecting MIDI patch cable DIN connector shielding and pins 1, 5

Tags: cables, pinout, midi

I am building myself a MIDI patch cable. According to resources such as http://www.leadsdirect.co.uk/technical-library/pinouts-wiring-diagrams/din-midi-wiring/ the middle pin of the DIN connector (pin 3) should be connected to the 'shield/screen/earth'. I am assuming it means the cable's shield.

What about the DIN connector's shield? Should that be connected to the cable's shield or left unconnected?

What do you recommend regarding pins 1, 5? Connect them or leave unconnected? Are there any cons to connecting them?

Answer (score 1):

The middle pin is not pin 3.

(CA-033) MIDI 1.0 Electrical Specification Update [2014] [says](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/midi-din-electrical-specification):

> The cable shall be shielded twisted pair, with the shield connected only to pin 2 at both ends, as illustrated in Figure 3, below.
>
> [image: MIDI cable]
>
> Do not connect the MIDI cable shield to the shield barrel of the MIDI plug.
>   Cable connection to pins 1 and 3 is not required by this specification, but may be present.